# The gutter between columns is 0.155 inches wide (on page 4), but should be at least 0.2 inches

Tags: margins, two-column, ieeetran

I am planning to submit a manuscript through EDAS and I am using the IEEEtran class (conference option). EDAS gives the following errors:

***The gutter between columns is 0.155 inches wide (on page 4), but should be at least 0.2 inches.***

***The top margin is 0.665 in on page 4, which is below the required margin of 0.7 in.***

I have looked up all the posts about the  Edas and gutter problems but I could not figure out the problem.

Since this error happens only on page 4, I think some figures, tables or equations have problems within this specific page.

Any suggestions, about possible commands which can result in such errors, are appreciated.

Comment: try to add in preamble `\usepackage{showframe}` and than see, if all pages are inside of page layout. then try rephrase content of fourth page or page before, that it will fit into frame. on the end remove `\usepackage{showframe}` from preamble!

Comment: what is this edas?

Comment: EDAS: conference and journal management system

Comment: If an equation in the first column is too wide, it will push into the gutter.  However, figures and tables should push down, not up.

Comment: Try \addtolength{\columnwidth}{0.1 in} for gutter between columns and \addtolength{topmargin}{0.1 in} for top margin issues.

Comment: For top margin, I have fixed the problem using the following command:  `\setlength{\voffset}{.041in}`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I resolved it by adding these packages:

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2 in}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this helped in my case as well! However, the first line does the trick (i.e., `\setlength{\columnsep}{0.2 in}`, adjust the size in case EDAS still complains), the second line just redefines the BibTeX logo with kerning specifications for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for my case

```
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.24in}
```

Comment: This suggestion (changing `\columnsep`) is already covered in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429362/5764).

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
    \subfigure[SubFiga]{%
    \input{figa.tex}
    \label{fig a}
}
\hfill
    \subfigure[SubFigb]{
    \input{figb.tex}
    \label{fig b}
}
\caption{Caption}
\label{subfig1}
\end{figure*}
```

In my case, the problem was the subfigure. Once I added \hfill between the subfigures, it started to work!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think your answer is related to the problem at hand (multi-column text _vs._ side-by-side figures)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help some people in the future. I had to change the code listings. The solution was:

```
\lstset{xleftmargin=1.63em}
```