# EDAS submission gutter warning

Tags: margins, ieeetran

I have uploaded a manuscript to EDAS and I am using the IEEEtran class with conference option. EDAS gives the following warning:
 
"**The gutter between columns is 0.155 inches wide (on page 1), but should be at least 0.2 inches**" 
Page one has only text no equations, no tables and no figures.
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This is the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428853/the-gutter-between-columns-is-0-155-inches-wide-on-page-4-but-should-be-at-le

Comment: @percusse it is but the answer there has a score of -1:(  searching for EDAS in the side box above shows that several people get that warning, and common advice is to ignore it (but perhaps some submissions refuse to accept documents with warnings?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just wanted to link them. I don't know what the issue is actually.

Comment: @percusse It seems the answer in the post that you have shared is working fine at least with me. I used the measuring tool in the adobe acrobat reader to check the distance between the columns in the first page of my paper. The distance now is (0.2")  (was 0.17"), but the EDAS warning still exists after uploading the modified manuscript. The warning says the gutter between columns is (0.19") instead of (0.155").

Comment: without your document and lack of edas system there is nothing we can do other than blindly guessing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The gutter between columns is 0.155 inches wide (on page 4), but should be at least 0.2 inches](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/428853/the-gutter-between-columns-is-0-155-inches-wide-on-page-4-but-should-be-at-le)